# Android SDK, brand new install and storm of errors

Tags: android, sdk

just installed Android SDK, trying to build "hello world" app example, but the build fails right out of the box. What. a. shame, Google!

First I had Gradle home directory not set. I changed that manually pointing it to gradle 4.4 folder in JDK installation folder. Then I had to manually set JAVA_HOME variable, now I am getting "License not accepted" error which I was trying to fix by running `sdkmanager --licenses` command. That also doesn't work. Here's the result:

```
C:\Users\OSC>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1

C:\Users\OSC>C:\Users\OSC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licen
ses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annota
tion/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(Sc
hemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHa
ndler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
ava:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
ava:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinCla
ssLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(C
lassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 5 more
```

I have no clue what this is about. Already spent 2 hours trying to get it to work and would appreciate your help.

Comment: As I know Android Studio works good after install without any additional actions.
Have you seen https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config ?
I suggest using Java SE Runtime Environment 8u171 or embedded JDK instead of JDK 10.0.1

Comment: That doesn't help. Luckily, internet is filled with folks like myself with the same problem. It's solved by (re)installing API version and accepting license agreement during that installation. However, now I have a bunch of different problems, but they are unrelated to this subject. What a joke :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Android Studio does not work on Windows 7 with Intel i5 CORE Duo E8400 CPU.
It does, however, work on "i5 CORE vPro M560".
I tried several different machines and looks like Dell Optiplex 780 is not your number one choice for Android IDE. VM's will not run, and IDE only works as text editor.

Don't waste your time fighting errors, you will not win. Just get different PC.

Answer (score 0):

Open sdkmanager.bat with notepad
Locate following line:

%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%
then and

add "--add-modules java.xml.bind"

It should look like this
%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% --add-modules java.xml.bind %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%